# How to execute a command for each lines in a txt file

Tags: python, linux

i'm trying to automate the research about a list of domain i have (this list is a .txt file, about 350/400 lines).
I need to give the same command (that uses a py script) for each line i have in the txt file. Something like that:

```
import os

with open('/home/dogher/Desktop/copia.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
        os.system("/home/dogher/Desktop/theHarvester-master/theHarvester.py -d "(line)" -l 300 -b google -f "(line)".html")
```

I know there is wrong syntax with "os.system" but i don't know how to insert the text in the line, into the command..
Thanks so much and sorry for bad english..

Comment: can you give a sample of file?

Comment: use subprocess module. Use `call` method instead of `os.system`

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
with open('data.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    os.system('python other.py ' + line)
```

If the contents of `other.py` are as follows:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

then the output of the first code snippet would be the contents of your `data.txt`.
I hope this was what you wanted, instead of simply printing by `print`, you can `process` your line too.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach subjects each line of your file to evaluation by the shell, which will break when (not if) it comes across a line with any of the characters with special meaning to the shell: spaces, quotes, parentheses, ampersands, semicolons, etc. Even if today's input file doesn't contain any such character, your next project will. So learn to do this correctly today:

```
for line in openfile:
    subprocess.call("/home/dogher/Desktop/theHarvester-master/theHarvester.py", 
         "-d", line, "-l", "300", "-b", "google", "-f", line+".html")
```

Since the command line arguments do not need to be parsed, `subprocess` will execute your command without involving a shell.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Linux tag i suggest you a way to do what you want using bash

process_file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#your input file
input=my_file.txt

#your python script
py_script=script.py

# use each line of the file `input` as argument of your script     
while read line
do
  python $py_script $line
done < "$input"
```

you can access the passed lines in python as follow:

script.py:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solution will be helpful for you :

```
with open('name.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        subprocess.check_output('python name.py {}'.format(line), shell=True)
```

Sample File I have used :

name.py

```
import sys
name = sys.argv[1] 
print name
```

name.txt:

```
harry
kat
patrick
```